# Stop a single quote from escaping a string in a WMI query powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

I have some code which uses a WMI query, but i'm running into an issue where the variable i'm using has a ' (single quote), which causes the code to malfunction

Here is an example:

```
$path = "\\SERVER1\Mike O'Leary$"
$servername = $path.Split('\')[2].Split('\')[0]
$sharename = $path -replace ".*\\" -replace "'", "`'"
Get-WmiObject Win32_share -computer $servername -filter "name='$sharename'" | Select Name,Path
```

The problem is that the share name contains a ' character so it errors out. Paths without ' work fine

I tried using the replace seen above but this doesn't help

I've tried various combinations of quotes but I can't get it right, can anyone assist?

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, turns out I should've been using \ instead of `

```
$path = "\\SERVER1\Mike O'Leary$"
$servername = $path.Split('\')[2].Split('\')[0]
$sharename = $path -replace ".*\\" -replace "'", "\'"
Get-WmiObject Win32_share -computer $servername -filter "name='$sharename'" | Select Name,Path
```

Mystery solved!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape that character in WQL. A [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-connect-to-a-folder-when-theres-an-apostrophe-in-the-folder-name/) that touches on this says you could escape it with a backslash.

```
$sharename = $path -replace ".*\\" -replace "'", "\'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes in your filter string:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Share -Computer $servername -Filter "name=`"$sharename`"" | ...
```

The nested double quotes must be prepended with backticks to escape them inside the double quoted filter string.