# How can I query WMI GroupUser objects when a group name contains single quotes?

Tags: c#, wmi, wql

This should seriously be a trivial escaping issue, but I can't query WMI for a group like so:

`SELECT * FROM WIN32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent="Win32_Group.Domain='TESTWIN7DEVEL-P',Name='Alaenna's Smile'"`

This returns a WMI error as shown here using `wbemtest`:

[image: WMI Failure 1]

I tried escaping with a backslash, as described in another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29920399/stop-a-single-quote-from-escaping-a-string-in-a-wmi-query-powershell):

`SELECT * FROM WIN32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent="Win32_Group.Domain='TESTWIN7DEVEL-P',Name='Alaenna\'s Smile'"`

This also doesn't work. From [another article](http://vbscriptwmi.uw.hu/ch19lev1sec1.html), I read the following:

> \ should be interpreted as a single backslash, and \" should be interpreted as a single quote

This query succeeds, but returns zero results. Because double quotes aren't permitted in Windows group names, I can't create a test group to see if the query is pulling a non-existent group called 'Alaenna"s Smile" or something else:

`SELECT * FROM WIN32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent="Win32_Group.Domain='TESTWIN7DEVEL-P',Name='Alaenna\"s Smile'"`

[image: WMI empty success]

I know for a fact that this query works as intended with groups without quotes. The following is an example query without quotes and the intended results:

`SELECT * FROM WIN32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent="Win32_Group.Domain='TESTWIN7DEVEL-P',Name='Administrators'"`

[image: Success example query]

**How do I escape a single quote group name using the WMI query above?**

This is being used in code to query for the members of a group (e.g. "Alaenna's Smile") in C#. I'd be happy with another solution that can accomplish getting the members of a all system groups or similar. I just figured this was the best, most direct route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with it for a while I've found that switching the quoting scheme should allow for you to properly escape what you're looking for.

Instead of:

`SELECT * FROM WIN32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent="Win32_Group.Domain='TESTWIN7DEVEL-P',Name='Alaenna\'s Smile'"`

Try:

`SELECT * FROM WIN32_GroupUser WHERE GroupComponent='Win32_Group.Domain="TESTWIN7DEVEL-P",Name="Alaenna\'s Smile"'`

Notice that double and single quotes are essentially switched, except for within the string `Alaenna's Smile`.